# Solidity learn -missing Store function

Tags: solidity

Hello I have decided to start Free youtube course about Solidity Language
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=5321s
after write this short contract simple storage
looks like function store doest work for me after deploy the contract there is no Store option on the left panel under Deployed contract
Im using Goerli Form VM instead of JAVA-it was unavailable on the list [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWYWq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57soL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he4cK.png)

Missing Storage Function

Comment: manage to Solved this thanks

Comment: So what was the solution for future reference and others with same problem?